# function with two horizontal asymptotes and f'(0) = 0

Tags: functions, asymptotics

I am trying to find a smooth function that satisfies the properties

$
\begin{align} 
\bullet &\qquad f'(0) = 0 \\
\bullet &\qquad \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = y_1  \\
\bullet &\qquad \lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = y_2
\end{align}
$

I had in mind something like the graph of $sech(x^2)$ with   different asymptotes on either side  ([sketch here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T287Y.png)). Is it possible to do this without composing piecewise functions?

edit: thanks for the responses! They made me realize I was not specific enough in what I was asking for. I need $f(x=0)$ to also be a global *maximum* if possible

Comment: You might try some sort of rational function, but use $|x|$ appropriately. (Of course, that's a "piecewise" function.)

Comment: @Ted-Shifrin good idea! Unfortunately w/ a rational function there could be discontinuities and I need the function to be smooth... perhaps I should have specified this in the original question.

Comment: How do you like this one? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jql50t0ehl . The point is just that $\arctan^3 x$ is the right shape and we can rescale it. If you raise a function to a power of at least 2, then its roots become points where the derivative is zero (chain rule).

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen very clever! Is it possible for f'(x= 0) to be a local maximum?

Comment: Well currently it's a point of inflection I think! You can make it a local maximum by adding on $e^{-x^2}$ to the whole function. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mfhqpuyara

Comment: You can certainly make sure there are no zeroes in the denominator!

Comment: Very cool! You arrived at a similar plot to @GEdgar from a slightly different approach. I realized it is my fault for not understanding/specifying that I need $f(x)=0$ to be a global maximum. Otherwise, you both perfectly answered the original prompt.

Comment: Are you asking the the derivative, $f'$ to be maximised or the function $f$ itself? To make the derivative be at most $0$, you just need the function to be non-increasing, so (if $a < b$) swap around $a$ and $b$ - ie work with $-\arctan^3 x$, which is decreasing. If you need $f$ to be maximised globally at $0$, you'll just have to add on a slightly bigger multiple of $e^{-x^2}$. Indeed just put it inside the parentheses so it's multiplied by $\tfrac 12 (b - a)$. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vdosckogjs

Comment: @TedShifrin ah of course! I will play around with it. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get two different horizontal asymptotes is to have a square root: $$y=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

To get this to have a derivative of $0$ at $x=0$, you need to just increase the exponents to higher odd powers (even powers will result in one horizontal asymptote): $$y=\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^6+1}}$$

Then if you need to have the $x=0$ point to actually be a maximum, add any function that tends to $0$ at both plus and minus infinity that also has a derivative of $0$ at $x=0$, e.g. $e^{-x^2}$, with a sufficiently large coefficient: $$y=\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^6+1}}+5e^{-x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\arctan(x)+\frac{2}{x^2+2x+2}$$

The idea is:  $\arctan(x)$ has two different imits at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.  But it does not have derivative $0$ at $0$.  And $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}$ has limits $0$ at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ and nonzero derivative at $0$.  So find a linear combintation of these with derivative $0$ at $0$.

[image: a]

Comment: Thanks for the response and great plot! However, I need f(x = 0) to be a maximum (updated the question to reflect this).

Answer (score 1):

This works:
$$
f(x) = 5 e^{-x^2}+2 \tanh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\tanh (x).
$$
**The graph:**

[image]

Comment: beautiful! I will go ahead and accept this. I found that by tuning $\lambda$ in $e^{-\lambda x^2}$ I could achieve pretty much exactly what I wanted. setting $\lambda = 0.2$ smooths out the extra "wiggle" in the solution.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ny4sulbi2t